# c programming using school server

Tags: command-line, c

I connect to my school server using the terminal.

I try to run my main.c on their computer.

but I do not know how to do it.

Should I copy the files to my school and then run or something else ?

what are the commands I need to write after I connect to school computers.

(school = university).

Comment: What do you mean _run main.c_ ? Display the source code ? Or you want to compile, then run the program ?

Comment: I want to compile the code and then run it

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you are logging in via `ssh`, using some command like: `ssh user@host.address.com`.

In that case first you have to **copy your *main.c* to the remote machine**:

```
scp main.c user@host.address.com:/home/homefolder/subfolder/main.c
```

Of course you have to **replace some strings in this command**. So "*user*" in the above command needs to be replaced with the right user name on your universities' server. Same goes for "*host.address.com*" which is supposed to be the login URL of your schools' server. Finally "*/home/homefolder/subfolder/main.c*" denotes the location you want to copy your file to.

Once done you can open a remote terminal as usual and `cd` into the directory that now has your *main.c* like this:

```
ssh user@host.address.com
cd /home/homefolder/subfolder/main.c
gcc -Wall main.c -o mainprogram
./mainprogram
```

The last two lines compile your c-Code and run it. Insted of `gcc` (the GNU compiler collection) your school might use another compiler such as the Intel C Compiler, `icc`.

Comment: I did what you told and it did not help because the terminal told permission denied (publickey, pasword). he also said stdin is not a terminal

Comment: Then you entered the wrong password. Its ab bit too little information you are giving us here. Your University must have a tutorial on how these things work. Maybe you should consult that. For more detailed error messages you can use `ssh -vv user@host.address.com` and edit your answer to include the messages that shows.